# Predicate Logic - What is the difference between these two answers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

[Main Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXjfr.png)

Okay so the question at hand is to describe this statement using set theory and possible from logic.

**Everybody is friends with everybody**

My answer would be for this:

**∀x∈S |{z∈S, f(x,x,z)}| = |S|**

however could someone clarify if this is the same as saying

**∀x∈S |{z∈S, f(x,z,z)}| = |S|**

If not, could you please explain the difference .

Thank you,

Comment: Both are correct answers, yes.

Comment: Okay thank you. thought so. Just wanted to confirm :) @A.M.

Comment: Why does $f$ take 3 arguments? It's supposed to represent the "_ is friends with..." relation.

Comment: Both answers seem to be wrong in case of an infinite population. Why do you use $|\cdot|$, i.e., cardinalities of sets instead of the sets themselves? Next, if you write subset of $S$ equals $S$, you can simplify further and reduce to predicate logic

Comment: Final remark: Natural language may not be completely logical. Many might use the sample sentence to describe a clique of close mutual friends (e.g., those meeting regularly in the Centra Perk cafe) while not agreeing that people can be friends with themselves …